# Android - PhoneGap Video Player plugin

Tags: android, cordova, webintents

I tried to write a little application to play video streaming.
I've found a `PhoneGap` plugin at https://gist.github.com/macdonst/1507162.
 I tried it,but it didnt work for me.

Does anyone have a sample eclipse project to send me?

Thank You very much !

Sry for my bad english, i'm french !

Or an other way for my problem could be how can I call an activity from my html page ?
I've test it :

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");



    /* Call MX PLayer */
    String videoUrl = "http://myserveur.com:1400";
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoUrl), "video/*");
    startActivity(i);


}
```

And It works fine ! Of course, when I launch application, it launch MXPlayer with the good link to video.
So How can I call MxPlayer from html page ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I will put all file on a server. Please wait few minute. Thx for your help.

Comment: http://217.169.242.205/video/